# About the focal length and $f\#$ of spectrometers

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, spectroscopy, lenses

Suppose I image light into the entrance slit of a spectrometer (actually a monochromator).
The spectrometer is schematically shown below.

[image]

On the spectrometer's specs sheet, it is said that it has a 750mm focal length and F/9.7 aperture.

Should I pay attention to the opening angle of a focused light imaged into the entrance slit of the spectrometer?

I.e., if the light enters into the slit with the opening angle on the left or the angle on the right?

[image]

If not, then what is it about the $f\#$ and focal length of the spectrometer that should be matched?

Comment: I am not familiar with the detailed design of spectrometers, but I would say that both parts of the optical system matter and can degrade the performance of the instrument (we are losing light due to the finite size of both, the collimating mirror and the focusing mirror), so the max. performance can only be achieved if both systems have identical limitation in light gathering power, which suggests they have to have equal f-stops. I don't know if the focal length matters except as an engineering parameter that dominates the overall size of the instrument. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two levels of optimization when imaging light into a monochromator which optimize the efficiency of the light throughput. Most important is to match the focal length $f$ of the imaging lens to the $f$ of the monochromator (which in this case is the $f$ of the collimating mirror), and to ensure that the light is collimated before reaching your imaging lens. This ensures that the light is properly collimated when it arrives at the grating, and is properly imaged at the exit slit.

The second is to match the $f\#$ of your external imaging system (single-lens or otherwise) to the monochromator. $f\#$ describes how great of an angle an optical system can collect light from and is defined $f\# = f/D \approx 1/(2\sin(\theta))$ where $D$ is the diameter of your so-called entrance pupil and $\theta$ is the half-angle of your focused light. $D$ is basically the diameter of the light which falls on your imaging lens. Matching the $f\#$ will maximize the amount of grating which is illuminated which can be important when maximizing resolution, but is not always necessary. You may find the wikipedia for numerical aperture (closely related to $f\#$) useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_aperture

Comment: In other words, if you're optimizing for throughput, you want an incident f# greater than the collimator's. If you're optimizing for resolution, you want an f# less than the collimator's. Since you probably want both, you'll want to match the f#.